# Confusion surrounding Mesh for a complicated function

Tags: plotting, geometry, parametric-functions

[image]I have two different setting with the command Mesh, one is at All and the other one is at 2000. I just don't have the math to understand what I am seeing.

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{Cos[x],Sin[x]}, {x,0,2Pi}], ParametricPlot[{((y^1/0.001)Cos[(x + (2 * 0Pi))/0.001]), ((y^1/0.001)Sin[(x + (2 *0Pi))/0.001])},{x,0,2Pi},{y,0,1},Mesh->2000], PlotRange->All, PlotPoints->100, PerformanceGoal->"Speed"]

Show[ParametricPlot[{Cos[x],Sin[x]}, {x,0,2Pi}], ParametricPlot[{((y^1/0.001)Cos[(x + (2 * 0Pi))/0.001]), ((y^1/0.001)Sin[(x + (2 *0Pi))/0.001])},{x,0,2Pi},{y,0,1},Mesh->All], PlotRange->All, PlotPoints->100, PerformanceGoal->"Speed"]
```

Comment: You need to make sure your code is syntactically correct. There are some brace mismatch problems here. Also, use the editing functions to make your code selectable as code rather than raw text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that you use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to investigate different settings for the option [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html). A value of `2000` is excessive.

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[
   {Cos[x], Sin[x]},
   {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
  ParametricPlot[{
    ((y^1/0.001) Cos[(x + (2*0 Pi))/0.001]),
    ((y^1/0.001) Sin[(x + (2*0 Pi))/0.001])},
   {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> mesh],
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"],
 {{mesh, Full},
  Join[{None, All, Full},
   {5, 10, 15, {0, 5}, {5, 0}, {5, 10}, {10, 5}}],
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you saying that it is excessive?

Comment: With 2000 mesh lines in each dimension any image would just be totally obscured by the mesh lines. Further, it would take an inordinate amount of time to render all of those lines.

Comment: Is it possible to say that it converges to a disk and diverges to a heptagon when it is partioned?

Comment: As @MarkMcClure pointed out, the artifacts arise because you are wrapping around the circle a large number of times. In the second `ParametricPlot` change the iterator to `{x, 0, Pi/500}`  Then all of the control settings in the `Manipulate` will produce circular disks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the patterns you see have little to do with the `Mesh` option an much more to do with the function you're trying to use, which you've written as:

```
{((y^1/0.001)Cos[(x + (2 * 0Pi))/0.001]), ((y^1/0.001)Sin[(x + (2 *0Pi))/0.001])}
```

Let's try to simplify and clarify this thing. First, the `2*0Pi` term is zero; it can be simply removed. Dividing by `0.001` is equivalent to multiplying by 1000. Finally, we can examine the boundary of the region by setting `y=1`.  Taking those into account, the boundary can be parameterized by

```
{Cos[1000x], Sin[1000x]}
```

If you let $x$ run from $0$ to $2\pi$, though, you get the following:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[1000 x], Sin[1000 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

That picture is not at all correct; the boundary should be just the unit circle. The picture you see is mostly an artifact arising from poor sampling. This should be expected, since you've traced the circle out a thousand times. You can improve this by either specifying `PlotPoints` or (better yet) reducing the interval over which you're sampling:

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[1000 x], Sin[1000 x]}, {x, 0, Pi/500}]
```

[image]

Applying these ideas to the region itself should make the result a bit more intelligible as well:

```
ParametricPlot[
  {((y^1/0.001) Cos[1000 x]), 
   ((y^1/0.001) Sin[1000 x])}, 
 {x, 0, Pi/500}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]